# problem writing/understanding Django Custom managers

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have problems with Django's custom managers. It may be simple but I did not understand the managers very well. here is my code :

```
class Season(models.Model):
    id       = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True)
    sku      = models.CharField(max_length=16, default=secrets.token_urlsafe(8), editable=False)
    title    = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    slug     = models.SlugField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    tutorial = models.ForeignKey(Tutorial, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    created  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects    = models.Manager() # Default Manager
    custom_obj = SeasonManager()  # Custom Manager in (managers.py)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Lesson(models.Model):
    id      = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True)
    sku     = models.CharField(max_length=16, default=secrets.token_urlsafe(8), editable=False)
    title   = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    slug    = models.SlugField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    season  = models.ForeignKey(Season, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Video(models.Model):
    id       = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True)
    sku      = models.CharField(max_length=16, default=secrets.token_urlsafe(8), editable=False)
    title    = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    slug     = models.SlugField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    content  = models.TextField()
    view     = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    lesson   = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    created  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    video_file   = models.FileField(upload_to='tutorialApp/videos')
    video_length = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The structure is the following: Every season has some lessons, each lesson has some videos and each video has a length.

I want to write a manager that shows the sum of video lengths in a season. (a manager that shows how many minutes of videos there are in a season)

And I also don't know which field type is the best for variable `video_length`? For now, my video_length is CharField so that when I write 1:14 it means it's 1 hour and 14 minutes. Thanks.

Comment: That wouldn't be the job of a manager. Managers are for queries over the whole set of Seasons, but you want to calculate a value related to a single Season.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you for your comment. So, what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I highly recommend you store `video_length` as an `IntegerField` of the number of minutes, so that you can more easily use it in arithmetic or comparisons.

Secondly, I think what you are looking for are aggregations/annotations [0] rather than managers, and used in conjunction with model methods [1].

So an example of what you might do is:

```
class Season(models.Model):
    id       = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True)
    sku      = models.CharField(max_length=16, default=secrets.token_urlsafe(8), editable=False)
    title    = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    slug     = models.SlugField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    tutorial = models.ForeignKey(Tutorial, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    created  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects    = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def total_video_length(self):
        season_videos = Video.objects.filter(lesson__season=self)
        aggregated = season_videos.aggregate(total_length=models.Sum('video_length'))
        return aggregated['sum']

# So that elsewhere you can do something like:
season = Season.objects.first()
total_video_length = season.total_video_length()
```

[0] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/

[1] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#model-methods